# How to access Azure Function with private endpoint with Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have Azure Functions with private endpoint and VNet Integration enabled.

I have Azure Data Factory with Azure Function Activity.

I'm getting error when triggering pipeline:

```
Call to provided Azure function 'myfunction' failed with status-'Forbidden' and message - '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Web App - Unavailable
```

Obviously ADF cannot access to Function. How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your azure function blocking the outside access of ADF make sure you are using below steps:

1. If you are using **web activity** of azure function it doesn’t support the URL that are hosted in private virtual network.
2. To migrate azure function-app to Isolated (within ASE)
   **App-Service-Plan** can fix your problem.
3. The Azure Function Activity supports **routing**. Your Azure
   Function has the endpoint `https://functionAPP.azurewebsites.net/api/< functionName>/< value>?code=< secret>`, then the **functionName** to use in the Azure Function Activity is `< functionName>/< value>`. You can parameterize this function to provide the desired functionName at runtime.

**Note**

> The functionName for Durable Functions should be taken from the **route** property of the function's binding in its JSON definition, to include its routing information. Simply using the **functionName** without the route detail included will result in a failure because the Function App cannot be found.

Make sure your ADF has setup as private end point. If not refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link#set-up-a-private-endpoint-link-for-azure-data-factory)

Refer  [supported and not supported in azure ADF private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link#secure-communication-between-customer-networks-and-azure-data-factory)

Example of ADF using Azure function activity [Link 1](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2019/01/introducing-azure-function-activity-to.html) & [Link 2](http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2020/04/using-azure-functions-in-azure-data.html)